# Making a holiday countdown discord bot and I want to only display days when the code is printed

Tags: python, datetime, discord

```
xmas = datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 24) - datetime.datetime.today()
halloween = datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 31) - datetime.datetime.today()
easter = datetime.datetime(2022, 4, 4) - datetime.datetime.today()

print(xmas)
print(halloween)
print(easter)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    message.content = message.content.lower()
    if (message.author) == client.user:
        return
    if message.content.startswith("xmas"):
        await message.channel.send(xmas)

#result of the print:
142 days, 10:51:05.203583
88 days, 10:51:05.203583
243 days, 10:51:05.203583
```

#I want to remove the time after or make it show the real time every time activated.

#At the moment the time only updates when I rerun the code.

Comment: use it   datetime.datetime.now().date()   in place of   datetime.datetime.today()